# Sagemaker: How to debug Model monitoring(data quality and model quality)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a Data Quality monitoring from Sagemaker Studio UI and also created using sagemaker SDK [code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69179914/11844406), I referred to create model Data Quality monitoring job.

**Errors:**

1. when there is no captured data (this is expected)

> Monitoring job failure reason:
>
> Job inputs had no data

2. From logs, I can see that it is using `Java` in background. Not sure how to debug?

> org.json4s.package$MappingException: Do not know how to convert
> JObject(List(0,JDouble(38.0))) into class java.lang.String.

[image]

Once we create the DataQuality monitoring job using Sagemaker Studio UI or Sagemkaer python sdk, it is taking a hour to start. I would like to know is there a way to debug monitoring job without waiting for a hour every time we get a error?

Answer (score 1):

For development, it might be easier to trigger execution of the monitoring job manually. Take a look at this [python code](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop/blob/main/labs/05_model_monitor/monitoringjob_utils.py)

If you want to see how it's used, open the [lab 5 notebook](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop/blob/main/labs/05_model_monitor/05_model_monitor.ipynb) of the workshop and scroll almost to the end, to the cells right after the "Triggering execution manually" title.